Clear notification badge from app icon when app is in focus
When an app has a notification, and I go to the app (for example to read my received message in an messaging app), it does not clear the notification count badge. It is only cleared if I manually clear the notification from the gnome panel.
Is there any way to clear the notification badge, as long as the app is in focus?
